# Exchange Admin loses access after name change

Tags: exchange

As part of a test of new usernames, I change my domain username.  It seems to be working, except when I launch the Exchange Management Console (2010).  Here's the error I get:

The following error occurred when retrieving user information for 'DOMAIN\username':
The operation couldn't be performed because 'DOMAIN\username' couldn't be found.

I made sure AD replication has taken place, and I had another admin update my alias, just in case.  The event logs on my local workstation and the server I'm connecting to don't seem to show anything.

What's really weird is that that Exchange Management Shell works normally connecting to the same server.  I can even do a get-mailbox and get-user on my account without issue.

If I rename the account UPN and SAM back to the original, I can access the Exchange Mgmt Console normally.

Does anyone have any ideas or any direction to look in?

Comment: If you change the name back to the old one, is that then working again?

Comment: Gave it a try and it worked.  Put it back to the new name and it broke again.  I've updated the original question with the new info.